# XAMPP - Apache service stops running after few seconds

Tags: apache-2.2, xampp

I have this big problem with my Xampp server, for some reason the Apache service stops running after a few seconds it as been started, and i have no idea what the problem is, and the error logs don't say much about the problem.

```
[Fri May 07 01:09:32 2010] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri May 07 01:09:32 2010] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri May 07 01:09:33 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 07 01:09:33 2010] [notice] Server built: Nov 11 2009 14:29:03
[Fri May 07 01:09:33 2010] [crit] (22)Invalid argument: Parent: Failed to create the child process.
[Fri May 07 01:09:33 2010] [crit] (OS 6)O identificador é inválido.  : master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
[Fri May 07 01:09:33 2010] [notice] Parent: Forcing termination of child process 36
```

> identificador é inválido (pt_PT) =>
>   identifier is invalid.

**Note:**

- No other application is using the Apache port.

I have done some changes to the httpd.conf file, but it as worked well for allot of time.

- Added some virtual hosts.
- Enabled xdebug.

As this happen to anyone, that could tell me whats the problem?

Thanks for your time.

**Answer:**

The solution as quite simple, i went to the Computer properties in Windows, Advanced tab, and then clicked Environment Variables, and changed the Variable `Path` for my user to:

```
C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk1.2\bin;C:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk1.2\emulator\bin;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Softimage;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
```

If you aren't sure what to write here copy from the System Variable `Path`.

That fixed my problems. Thanks to [Igal Serban](https://serverfault.com/questions/139418/xampp-apache-service-stops-running-after-few-seconds/139492#139492).

**EDIT 2**

I have disabled Perl and then Apache started to work properly. But i need Perl active. So any suggestions?

**EDIT 1**

[Igal Serban Advice](https://serverfault.com/questions/139418/xampp-apache-service-stops-running-after-few-seconds/139492#139492):

The result after changing the debug level on Apache:

```
[Fri May 07 10:38:58 2010] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 136 bytes of entropy
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(470): unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(414): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1)
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(607): Configuring permitted SSL ciphers [ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL]
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(370): Configuring TLS extension handling
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(738): Configuring RSA server certificate
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(777): Configuring RSA server private key
[Fri May 07 10:38:59 2010] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.14 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.14, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.8l
[Fri May 07 10:39:00 2010] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 136 bytes of entropy
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(470): unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(253): shmcb_init allocated 512000 bytes of shared memory
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(272): for 511952 bytes (512000 including header), recommending 32 subcaches, 133 indexes each
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(306): shmcb_init_memory choices follow
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(308): subcache_num = 32
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(310): subcache_size = 15996
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(312): subcache_data_offset = 2144
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(314): subcache_data_size = 13852
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(316): index_num = 133
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [info] Shared memory session cache initialised
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(414): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1)
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(607): Configuring permitted SSL ciphers [ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL]
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(370): Configuring TLS extension handling
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(738): Configuring RSA server certificate
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(777): Configuring RSA server private key
[Fri May 07 10:39:01 2010] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.14 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.14, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.8l
[Fri May 07 10:39:02 2010] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri May 07 10:39:02 2010] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri May 07 10:39:02 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 07 10:39:02 2010] [notice] Server built: Nov 11 2009 14:29:03
[Fri May 07 10:39:02 2010] [crit] (22)Invalid argument: Parent: Failed to create the child process.
[Fri May 07 10:39:02 2010] [crit] (OS 6)O identificador é inválido.  : master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
[Fri May 07 10:39:02 2010] [notice] Parent: Forcing termination of child process 36
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 3**: Check if there are environment variable pointing to a different perl installation than the one used by apache.

**Update 2**: With process monitor its "When you see it you will know!". You can look for failed attempt to read or write things. Notice (from the logs) that the fail is in the **Second** httpd.exe process. And it fails really fast. So you won't have many lines to go throe.
Other thing you can try, is disabling modules. Maybe the problem is related to a specific module.

**Update**: The logs don't help( I think). Try using [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Filter for httpd.exe image.

**Before update**: Try putting:

```
LogLevel debug
```

In you conf file. And post the result.

Comment: Done. Have a look at my latest edit.

Comment: And for what should i look for in Process monitor, related to the Apache process?

Comment: Haha funny xD. Only 13.652 events to see. I have noticed something. Have a look at my Edit 2.

Comment: You'r right. I had my Path variable miswritten, i guess that happen when i installed the Android SDK. I have copied from the System Variable Path, and then added what i needed for Android, and Bingo. Started working. Never occurred to me that could be the Path Variable in Windows. My gratest thanks Igal Serban.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the cause is user permissions? Try to run Apache as different user.

Comment: I even tried as admin. Same result.